# Is this the Correct Implementation for Finding Duplicates in Sorted Arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

I've been working on an assignment that involves optimizing a duplicate finding algorithm for sorted arrays, and I'd like to get your thoughts on the implementation. Here's the code I've come up with:

```java
private static int findDuplicatesFinalVersion(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int count = 0;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    while (index1 < arr1.length && index2 < arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[index1] < arr2[index2]) {
            index1++;
        } else if (arr1[index1] == arr2[index2]) {
            count++;
            index1++;
            index2++;
        } else {
            index2++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The assignment:

> Keep track of the next element in the first array. If the next element in the second array is smaller than the next in the first, then move forward in the second array. If it is equal (and then we found a duplicate) or greater, then we move forward in the first array. Assume that the two arrays themselves do not contain any duplicates (use the generator in the previous example). Run some benchmarks and compare the execution time with the run time using: unsorted arrays, binary search, and your final version.

This implementation is meant to find duplicates efficiently in two sorted arrays as per the assignment requirements. It keeps track of two indices, one for each array, and advances them intelligently based on the comparison of elements.

Before arriving at this solution, I also experimented with an unsorted array and implemented binary search, which significantly improved performance. However, for this assignment, I'm tasked with working on sorted arrays.

If you have experience with sorting and searching algorithms or if you've encountered similar assignments, I would greatly appreciate it if you could review this code. Do you think this implementation is correct and efficient for finding duplicates in sorted arrays as per the context of my assignment? Additionally, if you have any suggestions for further improvements or insights, please feel free to share.

Thank you!

Comment: Binary search only works on a sorted array. Do you mean one sorted and one unsorted?

Comment: @shmosel In the provided context, when discussing using binary search, it's assumed that both arrays are sorted. Binary search is indeed effective for searching in sorted arrays. If working with one sorted and one unsorted array, the binary search approach wouldn't apply directly to the unsorted array. In the assignment, it's suggested to compare the performance of searching for duplicates in two sorted arrays using binary search with the performance of other methods such as the final version of the code provided.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [codereview.se].